# Connecting with PostgreSQL 9.1 using the Ubuntu machine user and peer authentication method

Tags: authentication, postgresql-9.1

I want to connect to my local installation of PostgreSQL 9.1 using my machine user (who is vagrant). So, after reading PostgreSQL documentation, I thought I just needed to:

1. Add username map in `pg_ident.conf`:

   vp              vagrant                 postgres
2. Using the map in `pg_hba.conf`

   local   all             all             peer map=vp

But I'm getting the error

```
sql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "vagrant"
```

If I try to connect to my server using psql.

I guess I'm misunderstanding the PostgreSQL manual. But, how could I get what I need? (**locally connect with the user vagrant like if it was the postgres user**)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: That looks fine to me as written; where's that line in `pg_hba.conf`? Is there a prior line for `local` that might match the database/user combo before this one does? Did you reload/restart PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, there is a previous line in pg_hba.conf like: local postgres peer (meaning 'use peer authentication for local connection of postgres user, and I didn't add map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, there was a prior `pg_hba.conf` line that also matched the criteria, and didn't have a `map` entry.

It was being matched first, so the one with the map wasn't reached.

Comment: You're right! I've added the map=vp to the first entry of pg_hba.conf (local all postgres peer map=vp), and it works now. The user 'vagrant' is mapped with 'postgres', as desired. Thanks!